# Django: how to switch to another view with the click of a button?

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates, django-views

I am building a django app using django 1.9.5 and Python 2.7.11. My project (which I named djan_web) directory looks like the following:

```
djan_web\
    manage.py
    djan_frontend\
        views.py
        templates\
            djan_frontend\
                upload.html  
                djan_homepage\
                       index.html
    djan_web/
        urls.py
```

I am able to load `index.html`, which is my homepage here. In `index.html`, I have a button, which when clicked, I would like to load `upload.html`. Here are my the relevant files:

`index.html:`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <title >Django Wed Project</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="header">
    <p> some text </p>

    <div class="container" style="width:95%">

    <center>
       <div class="col-md-1 center-block text-center" style="font-size: xx-large">
       <a href="/upload-file" class="dark" style="cursor: pointer;">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></span>Let's get started!</a>
      </div>
    </center>
   </div>
   </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

`urls.py:`

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from djan_frontend import views
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', views.homepage, name="homepage"),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^upload-file/$', views.upload, name='upload')
]
```

`views.py:`

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

from .upload_file import UploadFileForm
from .models import Document
from .tasks import process_csv

def homepage(request):
    return render(request, 'djan_frontend/djan_homepage/index.html')

def upload(request):
    return render(request, 'djan_frontend/upload.html')
```

I am able to load `index.html`, but when I click the button `Let's get started` nothing happens except for the URL, where `upload-file/` gets appended to it.

I also tried using TemplateView, so I changed `href` part in the button definition to `href="{% url 'upload' %}"` and changed the third url pattern in `urls.py` to

```
url(r'^upload/$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='upload.html'), name='upload')
```

and deleted the `upload` function in `views.py` but I couldn't get it work. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried putting a `/` at the end of upload-file in your `a` tag?

Comment: Maybe should it be `TemplateView.as_view(template_name='djan_frontend/upload.html')` or there is misprint?

Comment: FYI you have 2 unclosed div tags in your HTML body.

Comment: As I said in my answer, you must change the first pattern.  It is matching every request coming in.

Comment: Thanks guys! @Jody's answer below solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix your URLs in `urls.py`.  Try:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.homepage, name="homepage"),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^upload-file/$', views.upload, name='upload')
]
```

Notice The `$` at the end of the regexs. You need to add end anchors to your url patterns, particularly on the first url pattern.  Without the ending `$` it matches on anything, so any request coming in is being directed to your homepage.

Comment: I think you have it wrong for admin.  That url is a prefix for whatever admin.site.urls has for its regexes

Comment: @joelgoldstick, yup you're right. wasn't paying enough attention.  corrected answer.

Comment: Right on! Thank you very much @Jody!